# Setting the css width of an element on page load based on a localStorage value without the user seeing the change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-core

By default the sidebar is 50px wide in site.css:

```
#sidebar {
  width: 50px;
}

#content {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

If the user clicks the menu toggle button I set the new size in localStorage and call adjust menu to adjust the menu to the appropriate size using jQuery. Then if the user changes pages on document ready I am retrieving the persisted value from storage, checking it and making the menu either wide or small based on it.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var storage= window.localStorage;
  var menuSize = storage.getItem("menuSize");

  resizeMenu(menuSize);

  $(".menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!$('#sidebar').hasClass('expanded')) {
      localStorage.setItem('menuSize', 'Wide');
      adjustMenu("Wide");
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('menuSize', 'Small');
      adjustMenu("Small");
    }
  }); 
});



function resizeMenu(size) {
  if (size === "Wide") {
    $('#sidebar').addClass('expanded');
    $('#sidebar').css('width', '180px');
    $('#content').css('margin-left', '180px');
  } else {
    $('#sidebar').removeClass('expanded');
    $('#sidebar').css('width', '50px');
    $('#content').css('margin-left', '50px');
  }
}
```

**The problem:**
If the user toggles the menu to be wide and then switches pages I can see the menu move from small to wide. I would like to prevent this and just have the menu be wide instantly. The flicker just doesn't look right. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Simple solution is to make it display : none , once page is loaded it will be decided to show expanded or not

Comment: I would do what Vivek suggests. However, if you absolutly must have the element visible and the right size right when the page loads, you could store your value as a cookie and then on the server side, use something like php to read the cookie and output the appropriate css rule, that would do it seamlessly.

Comment: You also could animate the `width` and `margin-left` with a bounce easing... in order to have a nice effect.